# ODBC node - CONNECTION_CLOSED_ERROR on ibm db2

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, db2, odbc

I'm trying to connect my electron application to a db2 istance using node-odbc library.

I have checked the ODBC driver installed into the system and all seems to be ok, so I have writed the following code to try connecting to the server

```js
        const conn = "DRIVER=IBM i Access ODBC Driver;SYSTEM=192.168.0.15;UID=myuser;PWD=mypwd;DATABASE=Iasp01"
        //IBM i Access ODBC Driver
        odbc.connect( conn ).then( (connection) => {
            console.log(connection)            
        }).catch( e => console.log(e) )
```

the code is inside the main.js file of my electron application and will be executed when the application will start. The mai problem is that everytime I try to connect I will get this error in VS Code console

```
 INFO  Launching Electron...
Connection {
  CONNECTION_CLOSED_ERROR: 'Connection has already been closed!',
  odbcConnection: ODBCConnection {}
}
```

My dev machine is under a proxy, probably I need to set it or there is something I'm missing?

**UPDATE**

when I try to use ibm_db library by importing it in the main process of the electron app, I will get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
    at Function.getFileName (webpack:///./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js?:178:16)
    at bindings (webpack:///./node_modules/bindings/bindings.js?:82:48)
    at eval (webpack:///./node_modules/ibm_db/lib/odbc.js?:57:86)
    at Object../node_modules/ibm_db/lib/odbc.js (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\tool\dist_electron\index.js:1125:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\tool\dist_electron\index.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///./src/background.js?:12:64)
    at Module../src/background.js (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\tool\dist_electron\index.js:3121:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\tool\dist_electron\index.js:20:30)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_./src/background.js?:1:18)
    at Object.0 (C:\Users\myuser\Desktop\tool\dist_electron\index.js:3144:1)
```

to fix an error of electron, since the front-end is created using vue, I've installed as a dev dependency node 16.

Comment: How did you install node ibm_db? Which version did you install? Which version of the i access driver are you using? Please put that fact into your Question.  Also please mention on which operating-system and version are you running the node-odbc,  and exactly how you verified the i-access driver __using exactly the same user-account as used by node ibm_db.

Comment: @mao I'm using node-odbc not ibm_db library. I'm on Windows 11 and I already have all the AS400 configured because we use it in our company to manage data. When I've tried to install ibm_db I've just run the npm i ibm_db command without any error. The library will not work because an error, please see the updated question

Comment: I need to connect my node script to the db2, never mentioned that I need to connect to vs code

Comment: The docs (https://ibmdb.github.io/node-ibm_db/) say that for Electron or VSCode you need to use specific commands (e.g. npm install ibm_db -electron=<electron_version>  , npm install ibm_db -vscode ). They also mention it automatically installs clidriver (it needs a license file to connect to i-series) __unless__ you explicitly set environment variable IBM_DB_HOME to point to the i series odbc driver directory __before__ you run the `npm install ibm_db...`).

Comment: @mao I've already tried to install the library with the flag for electron, but the error will persist. This is why I've opted for node-odbc

Comment: You are more likely to get success or support for the combination with node ibm_db. I'm not sure if the node-odbc will work on Microsoft-windows. You have not explicitly stated that you set IBM_DB_HOME correctly BEFORE installing node-ibm-db. This is essential if you want to avoid clidriver and instead use the i-series access odbc driver instead.

Comment: how is supposet to set the variable? `set IBM_DB_HOME` in cmd or powershell?

Comment: This topic of setting environment IBM_DB_HOME is described in the documentation and many places online. Easiest is to use `SET IBM_DB_HOME=path_to_i-series-access-odbc-directory`  in the same cmd session you will run the `npm install ibm_db -electron...` , but that is not persistent. To make it persistent use the Windows system environment variable settings and open a new cmd afterwards. You also need to ensure that the i series access odbc driver directory is on the PATH when electron runs, and whatever other required environment variables it needs.

Comment: the environment variable is set globally in my windows machine, but the error I've posted still remain also if I compile as I already did the ibm_db library for electron 13 that is the version that is shipped with vue-electron-cli plugin. I don't think it's possible to make it work

Comment: I suggest uninstalling node-odbc, uninstall ibm_db, keep IBM_DB_HOME variable set to the directory containing the ibm i access odbc driver. Verify the PATH contains the directory with the i series odbc driver, install ibm_db with the electron argument. Then change your code to use ibm_db.open(). Follow carefully ALL the linked pages at https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=applications-nodejs (when node runs on Microsoft Windows) along with the github page docs ( https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm_db )

Comment: @mao I've already saw that link from ibm but it's not helping about windows installation. As I said my system is already configured with all the necessary drivers for system i. I will google a bit to find a way to make the library work